# Open source desktop GIS for high school curriculum?

Tags: software-recommendations, open-source-gis, references, teaching

I am a physics teacher and contemplating to integrate GIS to our high school's curriculum. A de facto software looks to be ArcGIS, which is a proprietary software. 
I wonder what are  open-source alternatives that are suitable for high school students.

Are there any open-source desktop GIS and corresponding books that can be integrated into a high school curriculum?

Comment: If you choose to use QGIS, be sure to use the latest long term release (currently 2.18) rather than the newest version. Long-term releases are more stable, and better documented. 2.18 has many tutorials and guides available.

Comment: While proprietary, I believe ESRI products are [free](https://www.esri.com/en-us/industries/education/licensing) for students / teachers..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are interested in a desktop GIS application similar to ArcGIS but open source, QGIS is definitely the way to go.

There are even two books specifically for use in class rooms at https://locatepress.com/odg:

> **Open the Door to GIS** offers a way for teachers to use this powerful software in their classes without having to become experts, with freely downloadable Open-Source GIS, QGIS.

and https://locatepress.com/otw:

> **On the Way with GIS** builds on the introduction to GIS, established in Open the Door to GIS, featuring more advanced topics. Students will strengthen their skills and increase their confidence in a digital environment, while you guide and support them with pedagogy, not technical expertise.

Answer (score 3):

The well-known Qgis is an open source Gis which you might integrate in your curriculum.

But have a look here : [What are some good introductory books or articles about Open Source GIS for students coming from an ESRI background?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22030/what-are-some-good-introductory-books-or-articles-about-open-source-gis-for-stud)
There might be something helpful for you!